# Plugin maven-antrun-plugin causes xmltask to be not download in repo and build is getting failure

Tags: java, maven, xmltask

Having Maven build as with :

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.7</version>
      <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.oopsconsultancy</groupId>
                  <artifactId>xmltask</artifactId>
                  <version>1.14</version>
            </dependency> 
      </dependencies> 
</plugin>
```

for my project **groupel-orchestrate** ::

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>concat-hosts-and-install-uninstall</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                 </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Causes build to be failure as:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run
>   (concat-hosts-and-install-uninstall) on project groupel-orchestrate:
>   Execution concat-hosts-and-install-uninstall of goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run failed: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact
>   com.oopsconsultancy:xmltask:jar:1.14 in central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

What should i do to overcome this error?

Answer (score 1):

The plugin you are trying to use is not present on Maven central repository, but only on the Atlassian 3rd party [repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oopsconsultancy/xmltask/1.14). To be able to use, you'll need to add that repository to your build, as in:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>atlassian-third-party-repo</id>
        <name>atlassian-third-party-repo</name>
        <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/3rdparty/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```